# Modify XmlElement InnerText without removing child nodes

Tags: c#

If I have an XmlElement with the following InnerXml:

```
ab/cd <text:line-break /> efg
```

how can I break it up into three XmlElements with the following InnerXml, i.e. so that any slash (that is not part of the line break element!) is put into a separate element:

```
ab
/
cd <text:line-break /> efg
```

I currently have the following, but it removes the line break element, because it only works on the InnerText:

```
if (Span.InnerText.Contains("/"))
{
    // Create a new span for the slash
    var SlashSpan = Span.Clone();
    Span.ParentNode.InsertAfter(SlashSpan, Span);
    SlashSpan.InnerText = "/";

    // Create a copy of the original span for the text after the slash
    var SpanClone = Span.Clone();
    Span.ParentNode.InsertAfter(SpanClone, SlashSpan);
    SpanClone.InnerText = SpanClone.InnerText.Substring(SpanClone.InnerText.IndexOf("/") + 1);

    // Remove the slash and the text after it from the original span
    Span.InnerText = Span.InnerText.Substring(0, Span.InnerText.IndexOf("/"));
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting innerText, you can add (for example)
`new XText("ab"), new XText("/"), new XText("/cd"), new XElement("line-break"), new XText("efg")`
However, I believe the XML parser is free to coalesce adjacent text elements into one, so I'm not sure it will achieve what you want.  What's your goal in putting the slash in its own node?

Comment: I need to put slashes into separate elements because a third-party tool that processes the output requires it.

Comment: Can they be CDATA elements?  AFAIK, that is the only way it can work according to the XML spec

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it, but it works:

```
while (true)
{
    var SpanList = BodyNode.SelectNodes(".//text:span");
    var AnySlashesMoved = false;
    foreach (XmlElement Span in SpanList)
    {
        if (Span.InnerText.Contains("/") && Span.InnerXml != "/")
        {
            AnySlashesMoved = true;
            // Create a new span for the slash
            var SlashSpan = Span.Clone();
            Span.ParentNode.InsertAfter(SlashSpan, Span);
            SlashSpan.InnerText = "/";
            // Create a copy of the original span for the text after the slash
            var SpanClone = Span.Clone();
            Span.ParentNode.InsertAfter(SpanClone, SlashSpan);
            var FirstCNToKeep = -1;
            for (var I = 0; I < SpanClone.ChildNodes.Count; I++)
            {
                var CN = SpanClone.ChildNodes[I];
                if (CN.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text && CN.Value.Contains("/"))
                {
                    CN.Value = CN.Value.Substring(CN.Value.IndexOf("/") + 1);
                    FirstCNToKeep = I;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (FirstCNToKeep != -1)
            {
                for (var I = FirstCNToKeep - 1; I >= 0; I--)
                {
                    SpanClone.RemoveChild(SpanClone.ChildNodes[I]);
                }
            }
            // Remove the slash and the text after it from the original span
            var LastCNToKeep = -1;
            for (var I = 0; I < Span.ChildNodes.Count; I++)
            {
                var CN = Span.ChildNodes[I];
                if (CN.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text && CN.Value.Contains("/"))
                {
                    CN.Value = CN.Value.Substring(0, CN.Value.IndexOf("/"));
                    LastCNToKeep = I;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (LastCNToKeep != -1)
            {
                for (var I = Span.ChildNodes.Count - 1; I > LastCNToKeep; I--)
                {
                    Span.RemoveChild(Span.ChildNodes[I]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (AnySlashesMoved == false)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Still happy to accept a better answer if someone wants to suggest one.